# IndexError: list index out of range for insertion sort code

Tags: python, insertion-sort, index-error

[i'm not sure how to fix this issue (A level CS)

```
numbers = [12,10,16,11,20]

def InsertionSort(numbers):
    for index in range (len(numbers)):
        
        nextposition = numbers[index + 1]
        preposition = index 

        if numbers[nextposition] < numbers[preposition]:
            print('check1')
            while preposition > 0 and numbers[preposition] > numbers[nextposition]:
                temp = numbers[preposition]
                numbers[preposition] = numbers[nextposition]
                numbers[nextposition] = temp
                print ('check')
            numbers[nextposition] = numbers[nextposition + 1]
            
    print (numbers)
    return numbers


InsertionSort(numbers)
```

[Traceback here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjjGU.png)

Comment: please post the traceback as a text instead of image, thanks.

Comment: why write this : `nextposition = numbers[index + 1]` and ... `numbers[nextposition]` definitely you get out of range

Comment: @user1740577 what do i replace it with? i basically need the variables to point to the index of one and then the index of +1

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 errors.

```
nextposition = numbers[index + 1]
```

should be

```
nextposition = index + 1
```

And you iterate over the length of the range, so when it comes to the last time it nextposition is at len(range)+1 so you get out of range.

Comment: how do i change that or correct it to make it work?

Comment: In general, if you have a list of n numbers, and you want to compare each one with the next, you will make n-1 comparisons.

Comment: for index in range (len(numbers)): should have a -1 in there.

Comment: its still not working, o added the -1 and removed the two errors of index +1 thinking it should iterate on its own but it still doesnt work - theres no error but the output is totally random

Comment: I assume you are trying to sort the list. But I think your code is doing one iteration of a bubble sort, rather than an insertion sort. Check out the pseudo code on the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort
and you see there are two while loops. Your code only has one.